# Update 2 joined tables simultaneously on HANA?

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

Can I update 2 columns from 2 tables joined by foreign key with one statement in SAP HANA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SAP HANA up to its current version HANA 2 SPS 05 does not support multi-table updates (or inserts/deleted for that matter).

Depending on the use-case, you may be able to emulate the behavior via SQLScript, like e.g. so:

```
DO BEGIN 
   data_to_insert = SELECT id, stuff FROM DB;

-- update table 1
   UPDATE tab1 t FROM t, :data_to_insert d
          SET t.one_stuff = d.stuff
          WHERE t.id = d.id;

-- update table 2
   UPDATE tab2 t FROM t, :data_to_insert d
          SET t.two_stuff = d.stuff
          WHERE t.id = d.id;
END;
```