# SAP HANA update with join

Tags: sql, hana

Im trying to do an UPDATE on a HANA DB with a Join. An online SQL Checker shows a Valid Syntax and after i found this: https://answers.sap.com/questions/11364926/sql-update-join-error.html i changed the order too of my update. It still gives this error:

> sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "LEFT": line 3 col 1 (at pos
> 119)

The Update looks like this (censored cause it includes some Data from my Company):

```
UPDATE TABX AS a
SET b.att1 = 'XXX', b.att2 = 'ZZZ'
LEFT JOIN TABZ AS b ON a.att3 = b.att3
WHERE a.att4 LIKE 'YYY'
AND att5 = 'PPP'
AND is_valid = 'TRUE'
```

According to the Post on SAP Answers it should work. And i know i did this on previous SQL-Databases, but HANA is now the First time.

How do i solve this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to update 'TABX AS a' but the SET operations are being done on columns of table b.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update 2 joined tables simultaneously on HANA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710787/update-2-joined-tables-simultaneously-on-hana)

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's unclear if you want to update TABX (a) or TABZ (b), as already said yesterday.

Comment: @SandraRossi I didnt know which table i needed to update. I took the Select and changed it to an Update for that case.

Comment: You don't know which table to update. How is that possible that you don't know if it's to be `UPDATE tabx` or `UPDATE tabz`? I don't get it. Ask your colleagues to see who knows what table is to be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sure, the syntax is incorrect as can be seen in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20ff268675191014964add3d17700909.html) (note that there is no `JOIN` keyword).

However, the solution depends on the HANA version, that you are using.

- *HANA2 on-premise:* You can use the `UPDATE... SET... FROM... WHERE...` syntax (see [documentation incl. example](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20ff268675191014964add3d17700909.html)). In the `FROM` part you essentially do a cross-join and make it a left join using the `WHERE` condition.
- *HANA Cloud:* In HANA Cloud the `FROM` clause of the `UPDATE` statement has been omitted in favor of the more powerful (yet more complex) `MERGE INTO` statement (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_CLOUD_DATABASE/c1d3f60099654ecfb3fe36ac93c121bb/3226201f95764a57810dd256c9524d56.html?locale=en-US)).

Note, that the `MERGE INTO` statement also exists for HANA2 on-premise (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/3226201f95764a57810dd256c9524d56.html)), which is why its use is probably preferrable.

Your example using the simplified syntax should look like something similar to this:

```
UPDATE TABZ SET att1 = 'XXX', att2 = 'ZZZ'
FROM TABZ b, TABX a
WHERE 
    -- LEFT JOIN
    -- (pls check if this should actually be an inner join)
    (a.att3 = b.att3 OR b.att3 IS NULL)
    -- your other conditions
    AND a.att4 LIKE 'YYY' AND att5 = 'PPP' AND is_valid = 'TRUE'
```

Note that in any case, you need to use `UPDATE TABZ` as you ultimately update columns from that table (and not `TABX`).